# 2016 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Signal Processing's [1st moderator election](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/election/1) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: jojek] [image: datageist] [image: Peter K.]

They'll be replacing [the pro tempore crew](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/election/1), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/5673187614392320/0).

Comment: Congratulations gentleman!

Comment: Great to see that diamond beside your name, @jojek! And datageist's. Pity r-bj didn't make the cut.

Comment: What Peter said. Congrats all around.

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for your commitment!

Comment: just discovered this.  i'm fine about the cut, @PeterK. and fine about the 3 moderators we have.  (congrats particularly to jojek for joining the preisthood.)  but i don't see datag around very much.  hope to see more of datag in the future.

Comment: I see datageist's hand through the moderator tools.  They are not as heavy-handed as I am, but effective nonetheless. @robertbristow-johnson

Comment: I cannot remember the last time I felt satisfied with the outcome of an election. Let us call it a first then. Congratulations, thanx for your time and patience